# Contour integral property

Tags: complex-analysis

This seems to be something pretty fundamental about contour integrals, but I don't know how to prove it...I know I should use Cauchy's integral formula for derivative (since the problem is pretty much a statement of it), but I don't know what function I am using or why its derivative should be zero or 1 depending on the location of $\alpha$.

Let C be a closed contour in a simply connected domain. Prove that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{1}{z-\alpha} dz = 0$ for $\alpha$ outside C and $= 1$ for $\alpha$ inside C.

Comment: Can you prove it for a circle?

Comment: No, I can't. :( Why should it be true? I am supposed to know something about closed contours that I don't...

Comment: Can you compute $\int \frac{1}{z} dz$ over the unit circle centered at the origin?

Comment: See [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem).

Comment: I can compute that integral, yes. But there is no description of the contour here, so I don't know how to parameterize it.

Comment: Is there some constraint on what you're allowed to use to prove it? This is incredibly immediate from the residue theorem!

Comment: Yes, I don't believe the residue theorem is intended here since it is an exercise to prove the residue theorem later in the chapter.